# JavaScript Nested Object Variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to access a object variable in a data model dynamically using a variable passed in to a function.

Here is an example of my code:

### Data Model

```
var Sectors = {
    Automotive: {
        Question1: {
            Strongly_Agree: 43,
            Agree: 35,
            Neither_Agree_Nor_Disagree: 10,
            Disagree: 8,
            Strongly_Disagree: 4,
            Dont_Know: 10
        },
        Question2: {
            Strongly_Agree: 54,
            Agree: 33,
            Neither_Agree_Nor_Disagree: 12,
            Disagree: 5,
            Strongly_Disagree: 4,
            Dont_Know: 2
        }
    },
    Technology: {
        Question1: {
            Strongly_Agree: 43,
            Agree: 35,
            Neither_Agree_Nor_Disagree: 10,
            Disagree: 8,
            Strongly_Disagree: 4,
            Dont_Know: 10
        },
        Question2: {
            Strongly_Agree: 54,
            Agree: 33,
            Neither_Agree_Nor_Disagree: 12,
            Disagree: 5,
            Strongly_Disagree: 4,
            Dont_Know: 2
        }
    }
};
```

I then have a html select for people to use so they can select what Sector they are in. Then I need to pull the data from my data model depending on what Sector they choose to compare.

### Function to pull data

```
function getData(sector){
    return Sectors.Sectors[sector].Question1.Strongly_Agree;
}
```

If I then pass in the sector "Automotive" it doesn't work.

Any help would be great.

Sam

Comment: because it's a object and not an array

Comment: You seem to have one `Sector` too many. Try: `return Sectors[sector]...`

Comment: @PhilippSander, you can access an object property as a hash or dictionary way, because **Objects in JavaScript are _key : value_** pairs. So your assumption is incorrect. Try `var obj = { name:"Katsu", age: 24 }; console.log(obj["name"]);` You will get the value of `obj.name` which is `"Katsu"`

Comment: didnt know that! thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should like this:

```
function getData(sector){
    return Sectors[sector].Question1.Strongly_Agree;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JoãoCerqueira that worked perfectly.

Comment: No problem, hope I could help ^^